# How to fetch the intergers from a text file using c++ in visual studio 2013

Tags: c++, file-io

I'm making a small accounting console app for my project. Apparently I stucked at file I/O.
I've a file created to store the data of customer. It's format is as follows.(obj is a std::ofstream object)

```
obj << name << "\t" << ac_no << "`enter code here`\t" << l_bal << "\t" << txn << "\t" << bal;
```

I wanna do is to extract the last value under "bal". That is the integer value after 4th tab in the last file. content of file are something like this.

Name     A/C No   L_Bal   Tnx   Bal
Vikas    s00001   0   1000  1000
Vikas    s00001   1000    500   1500
I wanna do is to extract that 1500 and assign it to variable cur_bal.
I'm able to access the loc of tab character of last line using this code

```
iobj.seekg(-1, ios::end);
int j = iobj.tellg();
iobj.seekg(0, ios::beg);
for (int i = 0; i <= j; i++)
  {
   int p = toascii(iobj.get());
   if (p == 9) // succesfully finding tab char by ascii code
     {
        tab++;
        switch (tab % 4)
          {
        case 1:
            pos[0] = (iobj.tellg()); //1st tab position
            break;
        case 2:
            pos[1] = (iobj.tellg()); //2nd tab position
            break;
        case 3:
            pos[2] = (iobj.tellg()); //3rd tab position
            break;
        case 0:
            pos[3] = (iobj.tellg()); //4th tab position
            break;
          }

    }
    else if (p == 10)  succesfully finding newline char by ascii code
        {
            line++;
                    pos[4] = (iobj.tellg());    //'\n' position
            for (int i = 0; i < 5;i++)
            {
                if (i == 4)
                    pos[i] = pos[i] - line - 1; /* position of '\n' is shifted by 
no of line found +1. so corrected the value.*/

                else
                    pos[i] = pos[i] - line; /* position of tab is shifted 
by no of line found. so corrected the value. */
            }
        }
    }
```

What next I'm trying to do is where I i'm facing problem.

```
{int s = pos[3], e = pos[4]; //position in b/w which value of bal is placed in file
char x[6];
iobj.seekg(pos[3],ios::beg); // this is not take the pointer to desired placed.
iobj.seekg(pos[3]); //Nor did this.
    iobj>>x[0]; // and this is also not transferring any char or integer to the char array. nor did it do in next statements.
    iobj>>x[1];
    iobj>>x[2];
iobj>>x[3];
    cout << x<<endl;
    }
```

please help as I really can't figure it out. One more thing I'm not using c++/clr mode in visual studio as I'm using c and c++ libs.

Comment: so you want to read the last integer in the file right?

Comment: `tellg()` seriously??

Comment: @hasan83 Yes. Like in above case want to fetch out 1500.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ, tellg() will return me the position of pointer in file. to use that one must have to know what is last bal value. which is not allowed. One must update file via command line and to fetch position of all of variables value at one time I used integer array "pos".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying way too hard.

```
// skip header
std::string header
std::getline(iobj, header);
// read to end of file
std::string name;
int acct_no, l_bal, tnx, bal, curr_bal = 0;
while (iob >> name >> acct_no >> l_bal >> tnx >> bal)
{
    curr_bal = bal;
}
// current balence is the last balence read in
cout << "current labance is " << curr_bal << "\n";
```

Untested code, and it does assume that the file is formatted correctly, and that the name does not contain spaces. So you might need something a little more complicated, but your code is too complex for a simple problem.

On the other hand current balance is such an important concept that your file format is poor if you can only retrieve it by reading through the entire file.

Comment: that if he didnt have Name A/C No L_Bal Tnx Bal in the first line.

Comment: Thanks @john. This perfectly done the job.... I only wanna know one thing `(iobj >> name >> acct_no >> l_bal >> tnx >> bal)` working. Did >> operator automatically assign a value to a variable when it encounter a `\s or \t` character?

Comment: @VikasVerma yes, space and tabs (and any other whitespace) delimit the values that operator>> reads.

Answer (score 0):

A one way to do it would be to get the last line and then read it in. Not the most efficient way, but might get you started:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string getLastLine(istream& is) {
    string line;
    while (is >> std::ws && getline(is, line))
        ;
    return line;
}

int main() {
    ifstream iobj("test.txt");
    string line = getLastLine(iobj);

    string name, ac_no;
    int l_bal, tnx, cur_bal;

    stringstream ss(line);
    ss >> name >> ac_no >> l_bal >> tnx >> cur_bal;

    cout << cur_bal << endl;
    return 0;
}
```